# Is there a name for the law that in chemical reactions atoms are conserved?

Tags: history-of-chemistry

One characteristic of chemical reactions is the trivial fact that the number of atoms of a given element is conserved. This is not conservation of mass, albeit conservation of mass is a consequence of this fundamental property.

I guess that at some point in history philosophers found this basic property, probably somewhat around the time, when the law of constant proportions was found?

Does anybody now a name for that law? Or the name of the person that first stated it?

Comment: This isn’t actually a strict law, as evidenced by radioactive decay

Comment: It is the "Chemical equations must be balanced" law. Textbooks refer to this as the conservation of mass, even though mass is not exactly conserved. This usage reflects the history of the discoveries (8 years between conservation of mass, Lavoisier, and definite proportion, Proust),

Comment: @Andrew The question is only concerned with chemical reactions. Radioactive decay is not a chemical reaction.

Comment: @DrSvanHay - “Nuclear chemistry is the sub-field of chemistry dealing with radioactivity, nuclear processes, and transformations in the nuclei of atoms, such as nuclear transmutation and nuclear properties.” - to quote Wikipedia. Glenn Seaborg’s Nobel prize was in chemistry. Enough said.

Comment: @JonCuster, but are those processes considered to be "chemical reactions"?

Comment: For the topic of history of chemistry, consider also the SE site [History of science and mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: " the trivial fact that the number of atoms of a given element is conserved" . There was nothing "trivial" about suggesting that atoms exist. Dalton's theory or just atomic theory would probably be the name of the theory you are searching for.

Comment: I agree with Poutnik, this fits better with the history of science and mathematics SE, as it is about the evolution (history) of a theory. A theory should mesh with existing knowledge but can also change to incorporate new facts. In this case the conservation of mass during chemical reactions had been proposed, and then new facts about atomic structure cropped up and were then meshed into an updated theory of the structure of matter.

Comment: Daltons definition of the "atom" plus mass preservation.

Comment: @RayButterworth - Well, they are reactions and I think nuclear chemists think of them as reactions. You might not. I'm sure Glenn Seaborg thought of them as as chemical reactions.

Comment: @JonCuster, I would consider transformations *within* the nuclei of atoms as *nuclear* reactions, and transformations in the relationships *between* two or more atoms as *chemical* reactions.

Comment: @RayButterworth - I'm not doubting your stance (and generally agree with it), but none of us have the authority to declare what usage everyone else should use.